# Montar SQL com opções

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou usando o PostgreSQL num sistema de ramais e tenho aqui duas tabelas. Uma que armazena os ramais e outra que armazena a permissão de ligação desses ramais.

Essa segunda tabela está estruturada assim:

[image: Estrutura da segunda tabela e seus dados]

No sistema montei um filtro para trazer os ramais de acordo com o filro aplicado pelo usuário. No caso a consulta abaixo não está me retornando o resultado esperado:

```sql
SELECT p.ramal FROM servico.ramal_permissao_ramal p WHERE  p.cod_opcao_permissao_ramal = 'RM' AND p.cod_opcao_permissao_ramal = 'LC'
```

Eu precisaria que ela me retornasse o ramal 1426 mas não retorna nada. Eu estava usando o IN mas o problema é que o IN não aplica um filtro exclusivo.

Como posso otimizar essa consulta para quando o usuário marcar `RM` e `LC` ela me trazer apenas ramais com essas permissões?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está relacionando dois registros dessa tabela. Um deles como o `RM` e o outro com o `LC`. A forma padrão de relacionar registros é com o `JOIN`. Logo:

```
SELECT p.ramal
FROM servico.ramal_permissao_ramal p
INNER JOIN servico.ramal_permissao_ramal q ON p.ramal = q.ramal
WHERE p.cod_opcao_permissao_ramal = 'RM'
AND q.cod_opcao_permissao_ramal = 'LC'
```

Comment: Deu certo amigo, muito obrigado!